# Adding values to an array in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array in vba in excel. This array is a set size, it doesnt need to be variable.

For the life of me I don't know what I'm doing wrong in trying to add values to the array.
My code as it currently stands is :

```
Dim count As Integer
Dim name(１ to 361) As String
Dim tmp As String

Sub go()

For count = 2 To 10
    name(count) = cells(7,count)
Next count

End Sub
```

I've tried all manner of variations on this. cells(7,count).value, name(count).value, etc... etc...

But I keep getting errors telling me I'm missing an as or there's a generic syntax error.

Its really annoying to be falling at this first hurdle before i can even begin to do anything useful with the array.
This is pushing me to finding an arrayless solution but that would be working around the problem rather than actually tackling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first issue is that `go` is a reserved word.  Choose another name from your `Sub`.  Same applies to `name`.  There are also several other issues, see below

```
' Dont use key words as procedure names
Sub MySub()
    ' Declare as procedure scope
    '  unless there is a very good reason to use module scope

    ' dont use key words as variable names
    Dim cnt As Long ' Integer ' use Long by default
    Dim nm(1 To 361) As String
    Dim tmp As String

    For cnt = 2 To 10
        nm(cnt) = Cells(7, cnt)
    Next cnt
End Sub
```

Comment: Go is a reserved word? I know GoTo and Resume are, but please remind me how Go is used.

Comment: @doug don't know why, but try it with and without `go` and you'll see

Comment: Chris, I made the other reserved word changes, but left the Sub name as "Go", and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a dynamic array assignment

```
Sub go()
    Dim i as Long, N as Long
    Dim names() as Variant
    ' It will be initialized to names(1 to rows, 1 to columns)

    N = 10
    names = Range("RefToFirstCell").Resize(1,N).Value2

    For i=1 to N
        Debug.Print names(1,i)
    Next i

    'If you want to write back to the worksheet use `Range().Resize().Value2 = names`.

End Sub
```

Comment: Op specifically states _This array is a set size, it doesnt need to be variable_.  One would assume (perhaps incorrectly) that Op has a _reason_ for fixing the size.

Comment: The OP says the array "is a fixed size". This does not mean, it has to be fixed. It just is right now. I think it is fixed as a matter of convenience, of which I disagree.